# Spring Cloud Netflix & Spring Cloud Data Flow microservice arheticture

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm developing an application that must both handle events coming from other systems and provide a REST API. I want to split the applications into micro services and I'm trying to figure out which approach I should use. I drew attention to the Spring Cloud Netflix and the Spring Cloud Data Flow toolkit, but it's not clear to me whether they can be integrated and how.

As an example, suppose we have the following functionality in the system:
1. information about users

2. card of orders
3. product catalog
4. sending various notifications
5. obtaining information about the orders from third-party systems
6. processing, filtering, and transformation of order events
7. processing of various rules based on orders and sending notifications
8. sending information about user orders from third-party systems to other users using websockets (with pre-filtering)

Point 1-4 - there I see the classical micro service architecture. Framework - Spring Netflix Stack.
Point 5-9 - it's best to use an event-driven approach. Toolkit - Spring Data Flow.

The question is how to build communication between these platforms.
In particular - POPULATE ORDER DETAILS SERVICE must transform the incoming orders and save additional information (in case it needed) in the database. ORDER RULE EXECUTOR SERVICE should obtain information about the current saved rules, execute them and send notifications. WEB SOCKET SERVICE should send orders information only if a particular user has set the filters, and ORDER SAVER SERVICE should store the information about the transformed orders in the database.

1.

[image]

Communication between the micro-services within the two platforms could be using the API GATEWAY, but in this case, I have the following questions:

- Does the Spring Cloud platform allow to work with micro services that way?
- Performance - the number of events is very huge, which can significantly slow down the processing of events. Is it possible to use other approaches, for example, communication not through the API Gateway but through in-memory cache?

2.
[image]

Since some functionality intersects between these services, I have a question about what is "microservice" in the understanding of the Spring Cloud Stream framework. In particular, does it make sense to have separate services? Can the microservice in the Spring Cloud Stream have a REST API, work with the database and simultaneously process the events? Does such a diagram make sense and is it possible to build such a stack at the moment?

The question is which of these approaches is more correct? What did Spring Data Streams mean by "microservice"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the limited information in the post, it is hard to convince on all the matters pertaining to this type of architecture, but I'll attempt to share some specifics, and point to samples. Also for the same reasons, it is hard to solve for your needs end-to-end. From the surface, it appears you're attempting to build event-driven applications and wondering whether Spring Cloud Stream (SCSt) and Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) could help.

They can, yes.

The Order, User, and Catalog seem like domain objects and it would all come together to solve for a use-case. For instance, querying for a number of orders for a particular product, and group by the user. There are a few samples that articulate the data flow between the entities to solve similar problems. Here's a [live code-walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7AGQsM7ncA) of event-driven systems in action. There's another example of [social-graph](https://github.com/sabbyanandan/eda) application, too.

Though these event-driven applications can run standalone as individual services with the help of of message broker (eg: Kafka or RabbitMQ), you could of course also register them in SCDF and use them in the SCDF DSL to build a coherent data pipeline. We are expanding on more direct capabilities in SCDF for these types of use-cases, but there are ways to orchestrate them today with current abilities, too. Follow [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-#2331#issuecomment-406444350](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2331#issuecomment-406444350) for more details.

I hope this gives an idea. Try to build something small using SCSt/SCDF, prove it out, and expand to more complex use-cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What interests me the most - can the service in Spring Data Flow not only process events but also have a full REST API? In this case, it will be possible to scale this service, register it in Eureka, have access to it through the API Gateway and set up Ribbon for load balancing (as usual microservices in Spring Cloud Netflix)? Is this the right approach? Or should not mix these concepts?

Comment: SCDF's responsibility is to orchestrate the Apps into a coherent data pipeline through a well-defined topic/topic-exchange destinations between the Apps. What happens within the App is not a concern from SCDF perspective. If the App uses Config-server, sure; if it needs its APIs registered to a gateway or a service discovery, that's fine also - SCDF wouldn't interfere. It is fine to mix the concepts, as it makes sense for the requirement. As far as the Spring Cloud Stream or Spring Cloud Task opinions are retained in the Apps, SCDF should be able to orchestrate them as data pipelines.